# Not more than one

Tags: american-english, speech, meaning

What does “no more than one” mean in “no more than one of photophobia, phonophobia or mild nausea”?
Does that mean only one out of those three or nothing at all?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you looked up those words? They do not have special meanings here. Do you understand "more than one"? This is the opposite.

Comment: 'No more than one of A, B and C' declutters. A or B or C or Ø. _**Not**_ (B + C), (C + A), (A + B), or (A + B + C).

Answer (score 1):

This not a question of usage or grammar but more of logic. No more than one item taken from a list of items means taking one or none. It excludes the possibility of taking two or more.